# stuff funct returns duplicate records when used with inner join

Tags: sql-server

Hello I want to get user responsibilities List from reponsibility table with matching user_id from user table but I get duplicate records when I applied inner join on these tables.

User Table
[image]

Responsibility table

[image]

and here is the query.

```
SELECT DISTINCT u.[user_id], 
                u.first_name, 
                u.mobile, 
                responsibility = Stuff((SELECT ',' + responsibility_nm 
                                        FROM   dms_responsibility AS dr 
                                        WHERE  responsibility_id = 
                                               dur.responsibility_id 
                                        FOR xml path('')), 1, 1, '') 
FROM   dms_user_responsibilities AS dur 
       INNER JOIN dms_user AS u 
               ON u.[user_id] = dur.[user_id] 
                  AND u.territory_cd = dur.territory_cd 
GROUP  BY u.[user_id], 
          u.first_name, 
          dur.responsibility_id, 
          u.mobile
```

[image]

This query returns duplicate. but if I try to fetch responsibility without inner join like this then I get proper result.

```
select STUFF((select ',' + responsibility_nm from DMS_Responsibility 
where responsibility_id in (1,2) FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '') as res
```

[image]

I m getting confused as what is causing the problem.

Comment: Your second query includes an additional filter: `responsibility_id in (1,2)`

Comment: @Rohan: Could you plz define your RDBMS version and your expected output according to your above-defined data??

Comment: My RDBMS version is SQL server 2012 and my expected output is the last query result which should be the result of 4th column in 1st query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At last found the solution and fix in my query. What I was doing is getting all the records from DMS_User_Responsibilities for single particular record that's why it returned me all the responsibilities from DMS_Responsibilities table.

My query fix is.

```
select distinct u.[user_id], u.first_name + ' ' + u.Name + ' (' + 
convert(varchar(10), u.[user_id]) + ')' as Name, u.mobile,
u.email, u.start_dt, u.end_dt,
responsibility = STUFF((select distinct ',' + responsibility_nm from 
DMS_Responsibility as dr
where responsibility_id in (
select dr.responsibility_id from DMS_Responsibility as dr
inner join DMS_user_Responsibilities as dur
on dur.Responsibility_id = dr.Responsibility_id
where dur.[User_id] = u.[user_id] and dur.territory_cd = u.territory_cd -- This is the fix which i did, now its getting only the particular userid for the record.
) FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '')
from dms_user_responsibilities as dur 
inner join dms_user as u
on u.[user_id] = dur.[user_id] and u.territory_cd = dur.territory_cd
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

When you generated the for `XML`, there's no relationship between your `users` and `resposibilities`. Try adding a relationship during building the `XML`.

```
SELECT DISTINCT u.[user_id], 
                u.first_name, 
                u.mobile, 
                responsibility = Stuff ((SELECT ',' + responsibility_nm 
                                         FROM   dms_responsibility AS dr 
                                 INNER JOIN dms_user_responsibilities t1 
                                         ON dr.responsibility_id = 
                                            t1.responsibility_id 
                                 INNER JOIN dms_user t2 
                                         ON t2.[user_id] = t1.[user_id] 
                                            AND t2.territory_cd = 
                                                t1.territory_cd 
                                         WHERE  t1.responsibility_id = 
                                                dur.responsibility_id 
                                         FOR xml path('')), 1, 1, '') 
FROM   dms_user_responsibilities AS dur 
       INNER JOIN dms_user AS u 
               ON u.[user_id] = dur.[user_id] 
                  AND u.territory_cd = dur.territory_cd
```

Comment: Yes this query is working but not giving intended results, it gives the responsibility list but also gives duplicates though